# "what are the intentions of this girl" or "what the intentions of this girl are"

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence, word-order, time

I am writing an essay. Can you help me with the order of words.

"Even though it is not clear what are the intentions of this girl with respect to this boy, he is totally deluded and wants to buy something for her"

or

"Even though it is not clear what the intentions of this girl are with respect to this boy, he is totally deluded and wants to buy something for her"

For me the first option sounds better but I don't think the second one is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy with either version.  The first sounds more formal, the second is more commonly heard.  In the first version 'what' is, I think, a *determiner* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is right.

"...it is not clear *what* the intentions of this girl are..."
what = that which

The word order changes to "**what are** the intentions... " when a question is introduced by *what*.

Examples:

I don't know what the game is called.
He said: "What is the game called?

Comment: Sankarane is absolutely correcct. In the first example with 'what' with verb after it is an interrogative pronoun and in the second,'what' is a relative pronoun,and the writer's intention is to use it as such--the way we convert a 'wh' word direct speech into indirect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just wanted to keep it simple, but just added a little more detail.

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  The NP "the intentions of this girl" is a heavy constituent before a very light one, "are", so the heavy constituent can be extraposed, giving the other order (which IMO is stylistically preferable).

Comment: @Greg Lee: "Close, but no cigar"... I'd quote and post it as a question here. Is this some sort of idiom? Are you saying the choice is a matter of style?

Comment: Yes, it's an idiom, as googling it would tell you.  It means "That's almost correct, but not quite."  You're right that in the conservative standard, there is no subject-aux inversion in embedded questions.  However, I'm pointing out to you that there is another rule involved.  Yes, the choice is a matter of style.

Comment: Oh, I kind of guessed it. Thanks. Can you explain the non-conservative rule here for the sake of everyone?